# Facebook likes disappear

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have the following issue: I recently made a url rewriting change to my website. So I changed pages with url http://www.in2life.gr/features/notes/articles/261434/article.aspx to the slightly better http://www.in2life.gr/features/notes/article/261434/h-athhna-mesa-ston-hrono-istoria-se-21-eikones.html format.

Now, in order to preserve the FB like count in the old url, I made sure that I rendered the FB like button using the iframe with the old url: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=el_GR&href=http%3a%2f%2fwww.in2life.gr%2ffeatures%2fnotes%2farticles%2f261434%2farticle.aspx&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=125&action=like&font=trebuchet+ms&colorscheme=light&height=21. The problem is, the FB like count reset to zero! I am absolutely positive that this particular article had quite a few likes, but if you hit the FB graph page (https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.in2life.gr/features/notes/articles/261434/article.aspx) you may see the comment count (90) but the likes have disappeared!

Anyone know under what conditions could FB do that? Is it perhaps that in the new page I have put a canonical url in the new format, and perhaps FB parsed this and thought the old url is invalid?

Comment: Check with new link in graph api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well strangely enough, 9000 likes have magically reappeared in the graph response: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.in2life.gr/features/notes/articles/261434/article.aspx

I will never understand why FB chose to hide these likes 3-4 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug:

[Report 1](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/198757440247852) /
[Report 2](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/308562189288837)